# 50ms delay when returning from a function in rust

Tags: optimization, rust, audio, rodio

I apologise for my ineptitude, I am fairly new to rust and I have only been using it for a few weeks

I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    notes.push(note_array[24]);
    let now = output::play_oscillator(&patch, &notes, 1000);
let elapsed = now.elapsed().as_millis();
    println!("Elapsed: {:.2?}", elapsed);
    notes.clear();
}
```

And the play_oscillator() fn is as follows:

```
#[inline]
pub fn play_oscillator(patch: &SynthPatch, notes: &Vec<Note>, duration: u64) -> Instant {
    
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();

    for i in 0..notes.len() {
        let mut oscillator = WavetableOscillator::new(patch.oscillator_type.sample_rate.clone(), patch.oscillator_type.wave_table.clone());
        oscillator.set_frequency(notes[i].frequency);
        let oscillator = filter_processor::apply_filter(oscillator, &patch.filter);
        let oscillator = oscillator.convert_samples::<f32>();
        let oscillator = stream_handle.play_raw(oscillator);
        let _result: &Result<(), PlayError> = &oscillator;
    }

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(duration));

    let now = Instant::now();
    now
}
```

For some reason, the elapsed time between the end of play_oscillator() and the line where i print the elapsed time is 50ms, despite the fact that no code is being run here.

I have moved `let now = Instant::now()` to the `main()` line after where `play_oscillator()` is used and the elapsed time is suddenly 0ms, even though no code is actually being run between the end of `play_oscillator()` and the line after where it is called.

Could someone please explain where this delay is coming from?

Comment: The end of the function is where values that are local to the current function get destroyed (`dropped`). This is not visible as code, but does add to runtime. Does `OutputStream` have a significant `drop()`-implementation? It sounds like something that would flush it's buffers to the underlying stream... ?! Try adding a `drop(stream_handle); drop(_stream);` before `let now = ...`.

Comment: @user2722968 I have done this but the function still produces a 50ms delay, I need this to be around 8ms as this is a synthesizer and cannot have such a long delay. It appears that dropping those variables is causing the delay, how might i do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: @willxw It's not clear from what you wrote, did dropping before setting `let now =` prove that the drop was causing the delay? If so, then your solution should be to not create and drop new `OutputStream` objects every time you call the function. Create one ahead of time and re-use it.

Comment: Hard to say without a [mre] (in particular how are `OutputStream` and `WaveOscillator` defined?) but I suspect that you shouldn't create a new `OutputStream` and drop it each time you want to play a note. Instead you should probably create it once in the beginning and re-use it for each note.

Comment: @willxw I see you answered your own question. Please mark it as closed to people's attention is no longer drawn here. In a more general sense towards the problem you had: If a value takes a very significant amount of time to destroy within a critical path, you can always `thread::spawn(move || drop(value))` to spawn a new thread whose only job it is to do the destruction; if you have such values on a regular basis, you might even want to spawn a daemon-thread that listens on a pipe for such values to destroy. The Rust ownership model allows one to do this very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a more efficient audio handler within the Rodio crate. I used `sink` rather than `play_raw()`, thus removing the need to drop `_stream` and `stream_handle` at the end of `play_oscillator()` every time as this was causing the delay.